# Regain lost focus after requery-MS access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am displaying a recordset in a form in Access-VBA. Now the focus is on 10th record. After i do a requery, focus is going to the 1st record. But i want the focus to remain on the 10th record only. Van anyone help me on this please

Comment: This is the same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703567/ms-access-setting-teh-focus and in fact, it's better described here.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you can capture the record before you do a requery and then jump back to it.  Here is an example of how that works:

```
Dim TempRecord As Long
TempRecord = Me.CurrentRecord
Me.Requery
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "MyFormName", acGoTo, TempRecord
```

Comment: @Linger...thanks for ur reply....the variable TempRecord is showing the correct value of current record.still, after requery, cursor not moving to correct focus

Comment: *@Vinod Chelladurai*, can you link a picture of your form? Is it a sub form or continuous form that you are referring to?